# I m installing OROCRM so i have an error during the installation process

Tags: symfony, magento, orocrm

I m installing orocrm so i have an error during the installation process
this is my command php app/console oro:install  error is  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The process timed-out.
i have check the oro_install.log file there is no any error 
here is the instrucktion page i have followed http://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/book/installation
thanks

this is my console 
root@efttt-Intron-5t59:/home/eures/tance/crm-application/orocrm# php app/console oro:install

> Installing Oro Application.
>
> Oro requirements check:
>   +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Check   | Mandatory requirements
>   |
>   +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | OK      | Vendor libraries must be installed
>   | | OK      | app/cache/ directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | app/logs/ directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | Configured default timezone "Asia/Colombo" must be
>   supported by your installation of PHP | | OK      | json_encode() must
>   be available
>   | | OK      | session_start() must be available
>   | | OK      | ctype_alpha() must be available
>   | | OK      | token_get_all() must be available
>   | | OK      | simplexml_import_dom() must be available
>   | | OK      | PCRE extension must be available
>   | | OK      | Cache folder should not be inside encrypted directory
>   |
>   +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   +---------+--------------------------------------------+ | Check   | PHP settings                               |
>   +---------+--------------------------------------------+ | OK      | date.timezone setting must be set          | | OK      |
>   detect_unicode must be disabled in php.ini | | OK      | memory_limit
>   should be at least 512M       |
>   +---------+--------------------------------------------+
>   +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Check   | Oro specific requirements
>   |
>   +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+ | OK      | PHP version must be at least 5.4.9 (5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1
>   installed) | | OK      | GD extension must be at least 2.0
>   | | OK      | cURL extension must be at least 7.0
>   | | OK      | mcrypt_encrypt() should be available
>   | | OK      | intl extension should be available
>   | | OK      | icu library must be at least 3.8
>   | | OK      | web/uploads/ directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | web/media/ directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | web/bundles/ directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | app/attachment/ directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | web/js directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | web/css directory must be writable
>   | | OK      | app/config/parameters.yml file must be writable
>   |
>   +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Check   | Optional recommendations
>   |
>   +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | OK      | Requirements file should be up-to-date
>   | | OK      | When using the logout handler from the Symfony Security
>   Component, you should have at least PHP 5.4.11 due to PHP bug #63379
>   (as a workaround, you can also set invalidate_session to false in the
>   security logout handler configuration) | | OK      | PCRE extension
>   should be at least version 8.0 (8.35 installed)
>   | | OK      | PHP-XML module should be installed
>   | | OK      | mb_strlen() should be available
>   | | OK      | iconv() should be available
>   | | OK      | utf8_decode() should be available
>   | | OK      | posix_isatty() should be available
>   | | OK      | intl extension should be available
>   | | OK      | intl extension should be correctly configured
>   | | OK      | intl ICU version should be at least 4+
>   | | OK      | a PHP accelerator should be installed
>   | | OK      | short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini
>   | | OK      | magic_quotes_gpc should be disabled in php.ini
>   | | OK      | register_globals should be disabled in php.ini
>   | | OK      | session.auto_start should be disabled in php.ini
>   | | OK      | PDO should be installed
>   | | OK      | PDO should have some drivers installed (currently
>   available: dblib, mysql, odbc)
>   | | OK      | SOAP extension should be installed (API calls)
>   | | OK      | A JS Engine (node) is installed
>   |
>   +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> Dropping database schema... Database schema dropped successfully!
>   Clear the entity config cache Clear the extended entity cache Setting
>   up database. Process migrations...
>
> > Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\CreateMigrationTableMigration
> >     Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroOrganizationBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroSecurityBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroAttachmentBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEmailBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroUserBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\SSOBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroUserBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEntityConfigBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_3\OroEntityConfigBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_4\FixOptionSetObjects
> >     Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_5\DropFieldConfig
> >     Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEntityExtendBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_3\OroEntityExtendBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\IntegrationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroIntegrationBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\ActivityBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroActivityBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\ActivityListBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroActivityListBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\AddressBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroAddressBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\BatchBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroBatchBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroCalendarBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_9\OroCalendarBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\ConfigBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroConfigBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\CronBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroCronBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\CronBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\JmsJob
> >     Oro\Bundle\CronBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_1\JmsJob
> >     Oro\Bundle\DataAuditBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroDataAuditBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\DataGridBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroDataGridBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\EmbeddedFormBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEmbeddedFormBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\ImapBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroImapBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\ImapBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_1\OroImapBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\ImapBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_2\OroImapBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroInstallerBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroMigrationBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_1\OroMigrationBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\NoteBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroNoteBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\NoteBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_1\OroNoteBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroNotificationBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\ReportBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroReportBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\SearchBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroSearchBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\SegmentBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroSegmentBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\SidebarBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroSidebarBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\SidebarBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_1\OroSidebarBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\TagBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroTagBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroTranslationBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\WindowsBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroWindowsBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\WorkflowBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroWorkflowBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\CommentBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroCommentBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\DashboardBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroDashboardBundleInstaller
> >     Oro\Bundle\NavigationBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_0\OroNavigationBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\NavigationBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_1\OroNavigationBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\NavigationBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_2\OroNavigationBundle
> >     Oro\Bundle\NavigationBundle\Migrations\Schema\v1_3\OroNavigationBundle
> >     OroCRM\Bundle\ContactBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroCRMContactBundleInstaller
> >     OroCRM\Bundle\AccountBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroCRMAccountBundleInstaller
> >      --------------------------------------------------------------------                                                           >"Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException The process
> >     timed-out."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably due to dev log messages, try with the prod symfony env:

```
php app/console oro:install --env=prod
```

In the installation instruction on the [github project page](https://github.com/orocrm/crm-application#installation-instructions) mention this note also:

> Note: If the installation process times out, add the --timeout=0
>   argument to the command.

Hope this help